# How would you implement model combination when using sub tasks and two different datasets with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, classification

How could you use model persistence for sub tasks when using two different datasets? I created a copy of the original, and substituted 3 labels in my target column for another label.

For instance, I have a NLP multi-classification problem, where I need to classify the x  as 4 diffferent labels like 1, 2, 3, or 4. 1, 2, 3 labels are related, and their labels can be substituted as 5 so that it's now a binary classification problem. Now, I only need to differentiate between 4 and 5, but I'm still left with the classification between 1, 2, 3, which I'm not too sure how to use the initial classification (4 and 5 binary classification model) to help in the second model (classifying 1,2,3). I can't find any information if sci-kit learn allows this like Keras does. Thanks for any suggestions.

Currently, I'm using SGDClassifier and getting 90% accuracy on classifying between 4 and 5, but not sure how to carry it over for the multi classification of 1, 2, and 3. Is this feature not in sklearn?

I would assume it's similar to Keras.

---

**Edit:** 
After further research, I think it I would be using 'stacking models.' However, I'm having conceptual issues understanding how the second model is going to 'know' which labels (1,2,3) are substituted for 5?

One issue I'm running into is that, ensemble learners require that they are trained on the same data set. Mine is the same, except that it's not since I've subbed labels 1,2,3 for 5 so, it only has 4, 5 as labels. What would this approach lead to?

---

**Edit2:**
Each sample can only be labelled as one class.
A. The original target column contains (1,2,3, and 4).
B. The adjusted target column contains (4, and 5), where 5 represents 1, 2, and 3

A and B are two different CSV files, and the only difference is what is stated above, and both have the same features.

Fitting `SGDClassifier()` for each fold (10 folds):

`X_Train` = about (30000, 54) (vertically stacked)
-- `y_train` = ~30000

Testing on:

`X_test` = (2000 to 4000, 54)
-- `y_test` = (2000 to 4000)

How it is now:

```
clf1 = SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3)
clf1.fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted = [labels[int(a)] for a in clf1.predict(X_test)]
actual = [labels[int(a)] for a in y_test]
```

Comment: do a multi class classification(5 classes). 
I.e lets say if its class 1, then the labels for it will be [1,0,0,0,1]. for class 2 it will be [0,1,0,0,1] and for class 4, it will be [0,0,0,1,0]

Comment: Yes, I've done it this way, but I'm am trying a different method to get around the bias in the data set. This method would first discern whether it classifies as 4 or 5, if 5, then lets classify it further between 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: then you do need two classification models right ?

Comment: Yes, I suspect so. I'm just wondering how I would go about connecting the two?

Comment: simple enough. train a model to do binary classification 4 & 5. train a separate model to classify 1,2,3 . And when ever your first model returns 4, you need to invoke the second model with the same input to get 1,2,3 class. This is how you would have done also i believe. I am still thinking what is your concern here ?

Comment: Wait. Really? Can you do that with Sci-kit learn? How would I invoke the first model if I'm just using the simple:
 
`clf1 = SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3)`
`clf3.fit(X_train, y_train)`

Comment: did u find the answer useful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer  based on your simple code above.

we have X_train, Y_train.

Training model 1

```
#modifiying the labels for two classes. binary prediction.  1[1,2,3] & 2[4]   
y_train_copy = np.copy(y_train)
y_train_copy [y_train_copy <4] = 1
y_train_copy [y_train_copy >=4] = 2
clf1 = SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3)
clf1.fit(X_train, y_train_copy )
```

Training model 2

```
#training with classes 1 ,2, 3. filtering X based on Y
X_train = X_train[Y_train<4] 
Y_train = Y_train[Y_train<4]
clf2 = SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3)
clf2.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

now we have 2 models, clf1 (classifies 2 classes (1,2,3) as 1 or (4) as 2) and clf2 classifies individual (1,2,3) which is predicted as 1 in clf1 )

Prediction

```
predicted = clf1.predict(X_test)
#make sure you get 1 & 2 filled in predicted list
```

this will give the result for 1(1,2,3) or 2 (4)

```
further_prediction_X_test = X_test[predicted == 1] #filtering all thats predicted as 1 by previous model
further_prediction = clf2.predict(further_repdiction_X_test)
predicted[predicted==2] = 4 #rolling back to original label
predicted[predicted==1] = further_prediction #replacing the predicted classes from second model for which first model predicted as 1. (replacing with 1, 2, 3)
```

Note :

1. I highly recommend to integer code your classes, so that its easy to filter and work around with it.
2. Dont confuse 1 & 2 of the clf1 with 1,2,3,4 original classes in my above answer.

Comment: but is the class label 0 for it ? what is the size of futher_prediction_X_test ?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped this portion `further_prediction_X_test = X_test[predicted == 1]`. I ran it and it's increased my classification of 1,2,3 from initially 72 to 147 for 1. I will have to add another portion, but I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: So, is `predicted` supposed to have 1, 2, 3, and 4 at the time `predicted[predicted==2] = 4` is being processed?

Comment: do predicted[predicted==2] = 4 first.. at this moment, it will have 1 & 4. i.e. 1 from the first model, and 4 from the second model. then you are replacing 1 with their respective class values (1,2,3) from second model. at the end it will have 1,2,3,4.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what's going on but, when debugging, I ran model training 1 without running model 2. It returns a lower `accuracy.score` than when I replace the actual CSVs of the target column. None of the folds processed are higher than 90%, where as the CSV edited one has only one at 89% and rest are 90%+. Maybe I should post this as another question, but this is interesting.

Comment: if you can post with datasamples, would be great.

Comment: I think there are issues with the way I'm processing the data. Additionally, I keep running into issue expanding your method once more for classes [1,2].